# Why can't my shared users use my script I have written into the Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a Google Sheet for job tracking. I wrote a script to hide certain rows once a field is entered into a specific cell.

This is the script:

```
function myFunction() {

}
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("PRODUCTION TRACKER");      // Enter sheet name
var row = s.getRange('AK:AK').getValues();            // Enter column letter that has 
//the text "hide" and  "unhide"

s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){ if(row[i] == 'YES') { s.hideRows(i+1, 1); }   //Value to hide
 
}}
```

It's very simple and works just fine for me. But why does it not work for my Shared users?  This script is something that is done automatically once a cell has a certain value, it's not a button or anything.

Comment: Any errors logged?

Comment: Maybe they don't have permissions to modify that range

Comment: There are no errors logged that I can see. It runs perfect since I am the creator but when I go onto one of my shared users computer and change the cell to the value that should make it hide... it does nothing and remains unhidden.

Comment: Try to login as another user and a different browser.  Open up the console log in the other browser. Login and run the script see what you get.  Hoperfully you will get an error.  Otherwise you might be able to the Overview link on you browser to see the errors on your script.

Comment: If you are trying to hide a lot of row it will probably time out because the onEdit)() must complete in 30 seconds.

Comment: Please explain what you want the script to do in words because it's not clear to me what you goal is.  But my guess is that it could be a lot simpler than what you have

Comment: So in my google sheet I have created, the very last cell on each row is data validated with a "YES" option. What I want is for the entire row to be hidden once that "YES" option is selected from the drop down.  It works perfect for me, but not my shared users.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

It seems that your code does not match the description you have given at the last comment. Basically, this is what your code does:

For **every** cell edit, it shows **all** the rows, even if they were previously hidden, then the script rechecks each row in column AK for the value 'YES', and **hides those rows one by one**.

Given your use case, the script could execute a lot of sheet changes, i.e. `hideRows(i+1,1)` for each cell edit. Sheet changes are very slow and greatly impact execution time.

You might have reached the [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) of 90 min / day for triggers. Maybe not in your account, but in your shared users'.

### Solution:

Unless there's a need for this specific behavior, you can optimize the code by utilizing the [event object](https://developers.google.cn/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) in the function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "PRODUCTION TRACKER" && 
      e.range.getColumn() == 37 && 
      e.value == "YES") {
    s.hideRows(e.range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Note that you can still use the original code, but not inside a trigger.